# R: Aggregating by dates with POSIXct?

Tags: r, date

I have some zoo series that use POSIXct index.

In order to aggregate by days I've tried these two ways:

```
aggregate(myzoo,format((index((myzoo)),"%Y-%m-%d")),sum)

aggregate(myzoo,as.Date(index(myzoo)),sum)
```

I don't know why they don't give the same output.
myzoo series had the weekends removed.   The "as.Date way" seems to be OK but the  "format way" aggregation gives me data on the weekends.

Why?

Which one is the right?

I've even tried it `as.POSIXct(format(...))`

Comment: Does you have data with timestamps?  Please provide a sample of the data.  You may have timezones in the POSIXct object that are then shifting your data.

Comment: Consider `format()` as a poor and lossy conversion for dates. Don't use it. It may be convenient, and you be able to sort the format you picked, but it ain't a good represenation for dates.

Comment: Hi. strptime instead?   I don't provide data because I'm using big files and is a little bit complex.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to be careful when changing the format of a timestamp that includes time with a time zone, because it can get shifted between days.  Without any data, it's hard to say exactly what your problem is, but you might also try `apply.daily` from `xts`:

```
apply.daily(myzoo, sum)
```

Here's a working example:

```
> x <-  zoo(2:20, as.POSIXct("2003-02-01") + (2:20) * 7200)
> apply.daily(x, sum)
> 2003-02-01 22:00:00 2003-02-02 16:00:00 
                 65                 144
```